# Usage of Decorator pattern in baking program

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is this a good usage of Decorator pattern?  I'm trying to use Interfaces instead of Abstract classes.

(Component) Interface

```
public interface IBake
    {
        string Name { get; }
        double Price { get; }
   }
```

(Concrete Component)

```
 public class BakeBase : IBake
    {
        private string m_Name = "Cake Base";
        private double m_Price = 200.00;

        public string Name
        {
            get 
            {
               return m_Name;
            }
        }

        public double Price
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Price;
            }
        }


        public string GetCakeCost()
        {
            return "Normal cake is:" + m_Price + "and Tax is: " + (this.m_Price * 0.08f);
        }

    }
```

Decorator

```
class CherryDecorator
{
    IBake _iBakeModel;

    public CherryDecorator(IBake iBakeModel)            
    {
        _iBakeModel = iBakeModel;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Cherry Decorated Cake!";
    }
    public double GetPrice()
    {
        return _iBakeModel.Price + 100;
    }
}
```

Decorator

```
class CreamDecorator
    {
        IBake _iBakeModel;

        public CreamDecorator(IBake iBakeModel)            
        {
            _iBakeModel = iBakeModel;
        }

        public string GetName()
        {

            return "Cream Decorated Cake!";

        }
        public double GetPrice()
        {

            return _iBakeModel.Price + 50;

        }
    }
```

Client

```
 public class Client
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    BakeBase bakebase = new BakeBase();
    Console.WriteLine(bakebase.GetCakeCost());
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    CherryDecorator cd = new CherryDecorator(bakebase);
    Console.WriteLine(cd.GetName() + "  " + cd.GetPrice());
    Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    CreamDecorator crd = new CreamDecorator(bakebase);
    Console.WriteLine(crd.GetName() + "  " + crd.GetPrice());
    Console.ReadKey();

}
}
```

I'm getting the following, which is not the right total:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You missed a somewhat crucial point in the pattern: the *decorator* **must** present the *exact same interface* as the *decorated* object.

In other words, any `IBake` decorator should also *implement* the `IBake` interface, so that it's possible to decorate a cake with *both* cream and cherries!

Here's your `CreamDecorator`, fixed:

```
class CreamDecorator : IBake
    {
        public static readonly decimal ExtraCharge = 50;
        private readonly IBake _decorated;

        public CreamDecorator(IBake decorated)            
        {
            _decorated = decorated;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                var name = _decorated.Name;
                return name + " +Cream";
            }
        }

        public double Price
        { 
            get
            {
                var price = _decorated.Price;
                return price + ExtraCharge;
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is that you **call the decorated code**, and then *decorate* the result before returning it.

---

Also since we're talking about *money*, `double` is a bad choice of a type for `Price`. `IBake` should look like this:

```
public interface IBake
{
    string Name { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
}
```

---

As for the wrong price being output, there's your bug:

```
public string GetCakeCost()
{
    return "Normal cake is:" + m_Price + "and Tax is: " + (this.m_Price * 0.08f);
}
```

The base class *doesn't know* whether it's decorated or not, and shouldn't make that assumption, *it's just another implementation of the `IBake` interface*:

```
public static readonly decimal TaxRate = 0.08;

public string GetCakeCost()
{
    return string.Format("Price: {0:C2}\nTax: {1:C2}\nTotal: {2:C2}", Price, Price * TaxRate, Price * (1 + TaxRate));
}
```

Now that *looks* cleaner, but it's also flawed: `Cost` is a bad/confusing term, should be `Price`, `SellingPrice`, or `TotalPrice` - `Cost` could refer to what the bakery is paying to *produce* the cake, and would be used to calculate profits and gross margins. The tax rate shouldn't be hard-coded into a method that returns a `string` either.

Another problem is that the decorator would need to *override* the `Price` property for the base class to return the correct figure, and that's not how decorators work.

One solution could be to include a `TaxAmount` member in the `IBake` interface, and a separate member to return a `string` representation of the cake's price, which I'd call `PriceDetails`:

```
public interface IBake
{
    string Name { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
    decimal TaxAmount { get; }
    string PriceDetails { get; }
}
```

The base cake could do it like this:

```
public decimal TaxAmount 
{ 
    get { return TaxRate * Price; } 
}

public string PriceDetails
{
    get { return return string.Format("{0}\nPrice: {1:C2}\nTax: {2:C2}\nTotal: {3:C2}", Name, Price, TaxAmount, Price + TaxAmount); }
}
```

And then the decorators have nothing to change about these two, so they just call the decorated code:

```
public static readonly decimal ExtraCharge = 50;

public decimal TaxAmount
{
    get { return _decorated.TaxAmount; }
}

public string PriceDetails
{
    get { return _decorated.PriceDetails; } // add an "Extra" in the detail line?
}
```

At the end of the day, what you want to ensure is that the client code is always calling into the decorated instance - that's why it's important for decorators to present the same interface as the decorated type, and for all members to be accessed by the client code via that interface.

Here's what your client code could look like in a production application:

```
public class CakeOrderLine
{
    private readonly IBake _cake;
    public CakeOrderLine(IBake cake)
    {
        _cake = cake;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _cake.PriceDetails;
    }
}
```

An "order line" is *injected* with an `IBake` instance, but *has no clue* how/if it's decorated, it treats all implementations of `IBake` equally.

Your console client could do this:

```
var cake = new BakeBase();
var cherryCake = new CherryDecorator(cake);
var creamCherryCake = new CreamDecorator(cherryCake);
```

And then this:

```
Console.Write("{0:C2}\n", cake.PriceDetails);
Console.Write("{0:C2}\n", cherryCake.PriceDetails);
Console.Write("{0:C2}\n", creamCherryCake.PriceDetails);
```

Should output something like this, assuming `Price` is implemented as above:

```
Cake Base
Price: $200.00
Tax: $16.00
Total: $216.00

Cake Base +Cherry 
Price: $250.00
Tax: $20.00
Total: $270.00

Cake Base +Cherry +Cream
Price: $350.00
Tax: $28.00
Total: $378.00
```

---

I'm not a UML-ist, I think this fairly represents the concept:

[image: UML for the below linked code]

See the full code [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14913/conversation/the-cake-decorator).

Comment: Hmm....First decorator runs but....I'm getting a StackOverflowException on Second Decorator...

Comment: Can you add the client code to your answer?

Comment: @TheTruthIsInCode added some client code, with what I'd expect the output to be (slightly modified, I added `Name` in the `PriceDetails`).

Comment: This prints out the Base Cake Price 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14913/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-thetruthisincode).

Answer (score 6):

As I'm a more java programmer than C# but I try to answer you as good as I can.

The decorater pattern should be able to decorate multiple times.

Example : I must be able to decorate with cream and cherry and cream again.

In your implementation you can only decorate once.
Your decoration class have to implement the `IBake` interface to so that your test should be :

```
IBake bakebase = new BakeBase();
Console.WriteLine(bakebase.GetCakeCost());
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
IBake cd = new CherryDecorator(bakebase);
Console.WriteLine(cd.GetName() + "  " + cd.GetPrice());
Console.ReadKey();

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
IBake crd = new CreamDecorator(bakebase);
Console.WriteLine(crd.GetName() + "  " + crd.GetPrice());
Console.ReadKey();

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
IBake creamWithCherry = new CherryDecorator(crd);
Console.WriteLine(crd.GetName() + "  " + crd.GetPrice());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Getting Casting error from CherryDecorator to IBake..

Comment: that's why I put that your decoration classes has to implement the IBake interface

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd name your Interface *Pastry* since it's the abstraction of what you're using. Second, let's refer to the design "blueprint" of the pattern in UML. You've missed a few things:

[image: Decorator UML class diagram]

- PastryDecorator is an abstraction of the decorators. This is useful but not necessary to avoid repeating code in each decoration.
- Decorators decorate *something* - in this case, a Pastry - but you don't show the aggregation in your code.
- The `getCost()` method of the decorator first has to call the thing it's decorating, and then "decorate" the answer (add the cost) before returning its own answer. Again in UML:

[image: nested decorated calls in UML sequence diagram]